# Initializing size of 2D array in runtime using C#

Tags: c#, arrays, allocation

I need to create a 2D array where size of column is fixed as 6 but size of row may vary . How to give dynamic row size in 2D array ? 
Below is the code I tried but no luck.

```
int n;
string num = console.ReadLine();
Int32.TryParse(num,out n);
int[,] ar = new int[n,6] ;
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Comment: You have a typo: `Console` should be capitalized.  What do you mean by "no luck"?  Did the code compile?  After changing the capitalization of `Console` I was able to run it successfully.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683073/how-to-set-array-length-in-c-sharp-dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the way you're constructing the mulitidimentional array.  The following code is valid so I suspect your error is somewhere else:

```
int n = 9;
int[,] ar = new int[n,6];
```

I'm guessing your input is not coming through correctly so add some error checks to figure out what went wrong.  First, `Console.ReadLine()` has to be capitalized or it wont compile.  Next, make sure `TryParse` is actually functioning properly (it returns a `bool` indicating success or failure:

```
int n;
string num = Console.ReadLine();
if (num == null) {
    // ERROR, No lines available to read.
}
if (!Int32.TryParse(num,out n)) {
    // ERROR, Could not parse num.
}
int[,] ar = new int[n,6];
```

If issues persist, people generally appreciate more descriptive explanations than "*I tried but no luck*."  Make sure to inform people viewing your question that it was a compilation error or a runtime error and be as specific as you can.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Dictionary as so.

```
Dictionary<int,List<int>> numbers = new Dictionary<int,List<int>>();
```

And you could add an item like this:

```
numbers.Add(1,new List<int>(){1,2,3,4,5,6});
```

And to add numbers to a particular row.

```
numbers[1].Add(7);
```

And to access a number in a specific row and column.

```
numbers[1][2] = 34;
```

Comment: Collection classes are great but a `Dictionary` would involve far more overhead than most other solutions.

Comment: True, it was just the first thing I thought of for this rather unusual request.